# How to pass path variables correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, easygui

This looks for a file `indirsavefile.txt` and if found reads the single directory path stored inside to the `indir` variable. If that directory exists it tried to enter that directory.

If no `indirsavefile.txt` is found, or if the path written inside is not found, it opens a directory chooser dialog, the result of which it tries to save as the new `indir` variable.

```
import os

from os import path
indirsavefile = path.expandvars(r'%APPDATA%\lootbot\indirsavefile.txt')
print(indirsavefile)
print("proceeding to conditional...")

if os.path.isfile(indirsavefile):
    print("indirsavefile.txt found")
    # not sure what "r" is here for
    with open(indirsavefile, "r") as loadsavefile:
        indir = loadsavefile.readlines()
        print("marker1")
        if not os.path.isdir(indir):
            print("marker2")
            import easygui
            indir = print(easygui.diropenbox("Locate your DOWNLOADS directory root"))
else:
    print("indirsavefile.txt not found")
    import easygui
    indir = print(easygui.diropenbox("Locate your DOWNLOADS directory root"))
    # here save the new indir location to indirsavefile.txt

print("resulting indir location is:")
print(indir)
print("proceed to enter directory...")

os.chdir(indir)
print("Current working directory is",os.getcwd())
```

There are some extraneous `print` statements to help me track down bugs, sorry about that. When the savefile is found, I get this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/SYSTEM/CODING/PYTHON/import.py", line 14, in <module>
    if not os.path.isdir(indir):
TypeError: _isdir: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\lootbot\indirsavefile.txt
proceeding to conditional...
indirsavefile.txt found
marker1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And when the file is not found

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\lootbot\indirsavefile.txt
proceeding to conditional...
indirsavefile.txt not found
E:\IMPORT
Traceback (most recent call last):
resulting indir location is:
  File "D:/SYSTEM/CODING/PYTHON/import.py", line 28, in <module>
None
    os.chdir(indir)
proceed to enter directory...
TypeError: chdir: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not NoneType

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How do I pass a directory variable to `os.path.isdir` and `os.chdir`, and from `easygui.diropenbox` into a variable?

Oh, and feel free to critique the logic and simplify

Comment: Please paste the complete error tracebacks in your question, they are more complete (and easier to read...)

Comment: Oh and `if not os.path.isdir(r"indir"):` should perhaps be `if not os.path.isdir(indir):`. Do you see the difference?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel that was my old version, not sure how I still had it there, but it changes none of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the error line 15..._isdir: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list

This error doesn't match your code. I assume that instead of

```
if not os.path.isdir(r"indir"):
```

the real code is:

```
if not os.path.isdir(indir):
```

in which case the error is indeed to be expected, since in the previous line:

```
indir = loadsavefile.readlines()
```

`file.readlines()` does indeed return a list, as documented. You probably want `file.readline().strip()` instead (if you are sure the information you want is on the first line of course).

> TypeError: chdir: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not NoneType

This is also to be expected:

```
indir = print(easygui.diropenbox("Locate your DOWNLOADS directory root"))
```

`print()` does indeed return `None`, as also documented. You want:

```
indir = easygui.diropenbox("Locate your DOWNLOADS directory root")
print(indir)
```

> `open(indirsavefile, "r")`
>     not sure what "r" is here for

Err... It may start to sound like a running joke, but [it's documented too](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) ;-)

> Oh, and feel free to critique the logic and simplify

Well, you have an obvious duplication (the call to easyguy).

First thing first: you want to move the `import` statement at the top of your script (not that it changes anything technically but [it's the convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) and it indeed helps wrt/ maintainability)

Then you want to avoid duplicated code:

```
import easygui

# ...

indir = None # means: we haven't a usable value yet

if os.path.isfile(indirsavefile):
    with open(indirsavefile, "r") as loadsavefile:
        indir = loadsavefile.readline().strip()
        if not os.path.isdir(indir):
            # ok, still not a usable value
            indir = None

if indir is None:
    indir = easygui.diropenbox("Locate your DOWNLOADS directory root"))
```

Comment: If the user was to press cancel for the dir chooser dialog? Can I disable the cancel button or what would be the simple solution?

Comment: @Bricktop  I never used easygui so I don't have the slightest idea... but this is surely documented, isn't it ?